# How to highlight even rows on PrimeNG table

Tags: angular, html-table, primeng

I am currently working on an Angular project (V.14) with some PrimeNG components, and in this particular component I need to create an striped table. I have worked a lot with [boostrap's striped table](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#striped-rows) (which works by applying a different background to even rows than odd ones), and I supposed [PrimeNG striped table](https://primefaces.org/primeng/table/striped) would work the same, but it is not the case.

I can style my table using inline styles for specific parts of the table, but the rows are created dynamically, so I can't apply different styles for odd an even rows.

I add my scss code next:

```
:host ::ng-deep p-table {
    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #ADADAD;
    }
}
```

But this does not apply, every row has the same background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following solution:
just change class to  ***p-datatable-table***

```
:host ::ng-deep.p-datatable-table tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #000;
}
```